# Is it possible to have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M\| x - y \|$ under such conditions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on an open convex $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}.$ If $\| \nabla f \| \leq M$ on $A$ for some $M > 0,$ is it possible to have
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M \| x - y \|$$
for all $x, y \in A$?
I do not think so.

I went thus far, as the following indicates. By the mean-value theorem, given $x, y \in A,$ there is a $c$ in the line segment joining $x$ and $y$ such that
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = \big| \nabla f(c)\cdot (x-y) \big| = \bigg| \big[ D_{1}f(c), \dots, D_{n}f(c) \big] \big[ x_{1} - y_{1}, \dots, x_{n} - y_{n} \big]^{\top}\bigg|\\
= \bigg| \sum_{1}^{n}D_{i}f(c)(x_{i} - y_{i}) \bigg| \leq \bigg| \sum_{1}^{n}D_{i}f(c) \bigg| \bigg| \sum_{1}^{n}(x_{i} - y_{i}) \bigg|.$$

Since $\| \nabla f \| \leq M,$ we have 
$$\sum_{1}^{n}\big[ D_{i}f(c) \big]^{2} \leq M.$$
But since $\bigg| \sum_{1}^{n}D_{i}f(c) \bigg|$ need not be less than $\sum_{1}^{n}\big[ D_{i}f(c) \big]^{2}$ and $\bigg| \sum_{1}^{n}(x_{i} - y_{i})\bigg| $ need not be less than $\sum_{1}^{n}(x_{i} - y_{i})^{2},$ so we need not have the desired conclusion, ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|\nabla f(c) \cdot (x-y)| \leq  ||\nabla f(c)|| \cdot ||x-y||\leq M ||x-y||$ by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Many thanks. I overlooked such a key relation!